# Does the sequence $f_n(x_n)$ converge to $f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ in $X$, $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ in $X^*$, Does the sequence $f_n(x_n)$ converge to $f(x)$? Here $X$ is a reflexive Banach space or Hilbert space.

Comment: to clarify, in both cases, $\rightharpoonup$ denotes weak convergence?

Comment: Consider $X = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. What is a simple sequence converging weakly but not strongly to $0$?

Comment: Shouldn't there be at least some hypothesis of continuity of the $f_n$ ?

Comment: If the convergence is weak, then this needs to stated.

Answer (score 3):

Hint 1:

> Take $X = \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$.

Hint 2:

> Take $x_n$ as the $n$-th unit vector in $X = \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$.
>  Take $f_n$ as the $n$-th unit vector in $X^* = (\ell_2(\mathbb{N}))^* \cong \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$.

Hint 3:

> Check that both converge weakly to the respective zero vector. A proof is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)#Weak_convergence_of_orthonormal_sequences).

Hint 4:

> But $f_n(x_n) = 1$.

Comment: @ user66081 Why both converge weakly to the respective zero vector in Hint3? If $X=H_0^1(\Omega)$, $\Omega$ is a smooth domain, does the conclusion hold true?

Comment: It is for this particular example. You would have to construct other examples for other spaces.

Comment: @FengYoung: $X = H_0^1(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space isomorphic to $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$. A basis can be constructed e.g. via [GS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).